# Almacenar el valor de 2 inputs de un form

Tags: reactjs, formularios, redux, react-redux

Tengo un formulario y quiero pasar a la funcion el valor de los 2 input para luego enviarlos a la store, cuando uso 1 input funciona, pero cuando meti el 2º dejo de funcionar alguna idea de que pudo pasar?
me lanza este error `Form submission canceled because the form is not connected`

form

```
<form className="col-start-1 row-start-2 row-span-3 opacity-1 ml-3 w-full transition-all"
                    onSubmit={editDescription}
                  >
                    <input name="title" />
                    <input className="my-2" name="description" />
                    <button type="submit" onClick={() => setShow(false)} 
                    className="rounded bg-slate-600 py-1 px-2 text-white">
                      Save
                    </button>
                  </form>
```

funcion que envia que recoge y envia

```
const editDescription = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const { target } = e;
    const data = target.title.value;
    const data2 = target.description.value;
    console.log(data, data2)
    console.log(imag.id);
    dispatch(
      actionEditImag({
        id: imag.id,
        description: data,
        alt_description: data2
      })
    );
  };
```

luego en el slice tengo la accion pero creo que esto si funciona y el problema es mas de recoger datos y enviarlos al slice

```
actionEditImag: (state, action) => {
      console.log(current(state));
      return state.map((item) => {
        if (item.id === action.payload.id)
          return {
            ...item,
            description: action.payload.description,
            alt_description: action.payload.alt_description,
          };

        return item;
      });
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

Hasta donde yo sé, `event.target.title` y `event.target.description` no hacen referencia a los elementos dentro del formulario; sino a los atributos del propio formulario.

Para acceder a los elementos del formulario se me ocurre dos formas de hacerlo:

### Usar un FormData para obtener los valores

```js
const editDescription = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    let fd = new FormData(e.target);

    let title = fd.get("title");
    let description = fd.get("description");
}
```

### Acceder directamente a los elementos por su ID

Esta forma requiere que todos los elementos tengan el atributo HTML `id="loquesea"`,  en lugar de usar el atributo `name`.

```js
const editDescription = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    let title = document.getElementById("title").value;
    let description = document.getElementById("description").value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes acceder a los valores también así

```
const {title, description } = e.target.elements
```